# Parsing JSON in Facebook SDK 3.0 iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to parse some Facebook JSON data I get back using `graphPath:@"me/home"`.

Im assuming the data returned from

```
FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                              graphPath:@"me/home"];
```

doesn't need parsing, and i just need to extract the data through dictionary keys, im finding this pretty confusing. Im trying to put the data into a tableview, basically showing the users news feed from Facebook. Heres a snippet of data returned:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1156410856_4453627016238",
        "from": {
            "name": "Abbi ☆ Mathews",
            "id": "1156410856"
        },
        "message": "Aalllllllll over this tonight.......be there....gonna be booooom ting!",
        "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/185169_4453626736231_812066502_s.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=4453626736231&set=a.1166926850788.88722.1156410856&type=1&relevant_count=1",
        "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/og8V99JVf8G.gif",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "Comment",
                "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1156410856/posts/4453627016238"
            },
            {
                "name": "Like",
                "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1156410856/posts/4453627016238"
            }
        ],
        "privacy": {
            "description": "Friends; Except: Restricted",
            "value": "ALL_FRIENDS"
        },
        "type": "photo",
        "object_id": "4453626736231",
        "application": {
            "name": "Facebook for Android",
            "namespace": "fbandroid",
            "id": "350685531728"
        },
        "created_time": "2012-08-25T14:08:11+0000",
        "updated_time": "2012-08-25T14:08:11+0000",
        "comments": {
            "count": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "7147617470_10150998196922471",
        "from": {
            "name": "The Fratellis",
            "category": "Musician/band",
            "id": "7147617470"
        },
        "picture": "http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=123966167614127&v=1&size=z&cksum=77469f27ebc292a58b3ee8ffb8183582&src=https%3A%2F%2Fd12nfv3nknyhzq.cloudfront.net%2Fimages%2Fartists%2F1208090326852218_medium.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.bandsintown.com/event/5469167/facebook_rsvp?artist=The+Fratellis&came_from=90",
        "name": "Next Month: The Fratellis @ Academy in Oxford, United Kingdom",
        "caption": "Saturday, September 22, 2012 at 7:00pm",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "Tickets",
                "text": "http://bnds.in/Nq9prK",
                "href": "http://www.bandsintown.com/event/5469167/buy_tickets?affil_code=fb_7147617470_auto_promote_month_before_targeted&artist=The+Fratellis"
            },
            {
                "name": "More Tour Dates",
                "text": "http://bnds.in/O9NLwd",
                "href": "http://www.bandsintown.com/TheFratellis/facebookapp?came_from=90"
            }
        ],
        "icon": "http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85006/251/123966167614127/app_2_123966167614127_7663.gif",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "Comment",
                "link": "http://www.facebook.com/7147617470/posts/10150998196922471"
            },
            {
                "name": "Like",
                "link": "http://www.facebook.com/7147617470/posts/10150998196922471"
            },
            {
                "name": "RSVP",
                "link": "http://www.bandsintown.com/event/5469167/facebook_rsvp?artist=The+Fratellis&came_from=90"
            }
        ],
        "privacy": {
            "description": "United Kingdom",
            "value": "CUSTOM"
        },
        "type": "link",
        "application": {
            "name": "Bandsintown",
            "namespace": "concertsbybit",
            "id": "123966167614127"
        },
        "created_time": "2012-08-25T14:06:39+0000",
        "updated_time": "2012-08-25T14:14:01+0000",
        "likes": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Derek Moore",
                    "id": "536043117"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Louise Berry",
                    "id": "1310689257"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jack Barber",
                    "id": "100002857426027"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Becky Hoddinott",
                    "id": "100000168277953"
                }
            ],
            "count": 8
        },
        "comments": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "7147617470_10150998196922471_22699715",
                    "from": {
                        "name": "Becky Hoddinott",
                        "id": "100000168277953"
                    },
                    "message": "Yesssssss! <3",
                    "created_time": "2012-08-25T14:14:01+0000"
                }
            ],
            "count": 1
        }
    },
    {
```

Ive been trying to put this into a tableview, but the UILabels are just blank, so what keys do  i use to get this to work??

Heres All the Code:

```
-(void)sendRequests {
  FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
  FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                                graphPath:@"me/home"];

  [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error &&  result) {
        NSLog(@"Pre Parsed Data = %@", result);
        NSArray *arrayRsult = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        for (_FBData in arrayRsult){
          [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
      } else if (error) {             
        NSLog(@"Error Fetching Data = %@", error);
      }
    }];

  [connection start];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  FaceBookCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[FaceBookCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    NSLog(@"Intialise Cell");
  }

  NSMutableDictionary *fbText = [_FBData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *name = [[fbText objectForKey:@"from"] objectForKey:@"name"];
  NSString *dateCreated = [fbText objectForKey:@"created_time"];
  NSString *message = [fbText objectForKey:@"message"];

  [cell.name setText:name];
  [cell.message setText:message];
  [cell.time setText:dateCreated];

  NSLog(@"Names = %@", name);

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime type of `result`? Debug your code with a breakpoint inside the `completionHeader` block and investigate `result`.

Comment: Im slightly confused by what you mean, result returns the data above, i need to know how i use this data to populate a uitableview with the users news feed.

Comment: The data above can be an NSString, NSDictionary, or something completely different. For example, if it is NSString, you'll have to parse it, so it's important to understand what you're dealing with, either through the debugger or finding Facebook documentation about that. To use the debugger, stop at a breakpoint and issue the following command in the debugger console: `po [result class]`. The last word of the printout should be the class of `result`. Once you figure out the class, you should refer to docs of this class to learn how to work with it.

Comment: Yeah its a NSMutableDictionary. The Facebook Documentation from what i can see is no good, i cant find anything useful to do with the above question.

Comment: This feels to be quite easy to solve with a little of a debugger...

Comment: I do not follow, surely the problem is I'm not using the correct key?

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you can't expect ~50 lines of code using a complicated 3rd-party framework to just work the first time you write it, especially if you don't have much experience in this... I suggest taking it apart and checking every part separately.